# Картинка в html коде

Tags: drupal, html, cms, css

Пишу сайт на друпале. Содержимое страницы пишу в FullHTML'e. Весь текст отображается как надо, кроме картинки. Картинка вообще не отображается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую папку надо скидывать картинки на drupal7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем IMCE.
А вообще картинки по-умолчанию должны быть в директории sites/default/files

Comment: А путь такой же прописывать в html sites/default/files?

Comment: В директории sites/default/files лучше создайте папку images и картинки размещайте там. Путь указывать тот же

Comment: Рекомендую поставить модули WISYWIG и IMCE. Проще будет создавать страницы.

Comment: А как включить WISYWIG?

Comment: Модуль установил?

Comment: Установил.Я как понимаю потом надо выбрать нужную библиотеку. Как я понял, самая лучшая это CKEditor. Но там написано "Do NOT download the "CKEditor for Drupal" edition". А потом когда ставишь этот компонент пишет, что то наподобе не находит версию.